# Does a magnet floating over a superconductor slowly fall and take infinite time to stabilize?

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity

The reasoning being that as the magnet moves towards the superconductor it induces an opposite magnetic field, until the latter rises sufficiently to equal the weight of the magnet. Except that looks like an iterative process that tails off at infinity.
Same argument applies if you view the superconductor as not allowing any flux penetration.

Comment: At least when I've observed the Meissner effect, to me it appeared that the magnet stabilized its position in a finite time hovering above the superconductor. Please clarify your question. What makes you believe it might be different?

Comment: I agree that this requires clarification. In particular, you use words like iterative process and tailing off at infinity which suggest that you have some equations in mind... can you write them down for us?

Comment: Not easily. Intuitively, I would expect that dropping a magnet above a superconductor would cause it to bounce, only coming to rest after air friction and eddy currents in the magnet dissipated the energy. Does this happen experimentally?